# Show all posts created from specific year

Tags: node.js, mongodb, keystonejs

I created all the links to send a number with the specified year that the user wants to see. Now all I want to set the routes use that year and display the posts created that year. Basically the number that will go to the routes is for example 2001. What do I need to add here?

Routes

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var async = require('async');

exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
    var locals = res.locals;
    // This gets category spesified on link
    // and then use it to show
    // post from that category
    var val = req.url;
    var gc = val.substr(val.indexOf("&") + 1);

    // This gets Year spesified on link
    // and then use it to show
    // post from that year
    var gy = req.url;
    gy = gy.replace(/\D/g, '');
    gy = gy.substring(0, 4);

    // Init locals
    locals.section = 'exam_per_year';
    locals.filters = {
        category: req.params.category,
    };
    locals.data = {
        posts: [],
        categories: [],
    };
    // Load the posts
    view.on('init', function(next) {
        var c = keystone.list('PostCategory').model.findOne().where('key').equals(gc).exec(function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                var gcid = results._id;
                var q = keystone.list('Post').paginate({
                    page: req.query.page || 1,
                    perPage: 20,
                    maxPages: 100,
                }).where('state', 'published').where('categories').equals(gcid);
                q.exec(function(err, results) {
                    if (results && !err) {
                        locals.data.posts  = results.Array.map(function(curResult) {
                            return curResult.getFullYear() === gy; // Your year goes here
                        });
                        return next();
                    }
                // else { // You either have no posts or there was an error loading them}
                });
                // q.exec(function(err, results) {
                //  locals.data.posts = results;
                //  next(err);
                // });
            }
        });
    });
    // Render the view
    view.render('exam_per_year');
};
```

***This is the model***

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

/**
 * Post Model
 * ==========
 */

var Post = new keystone.List('Post', {
    map: { name: 'title' },
    autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'title', unique: true },
});

Post.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    categories: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'PostCategory', many: true },
    state: { type: Types.Select, options: 'draft, published, archived', default: 'published', index: true },
    publishedDate: { type: Types.Date, index: true, dependsOn: { state: 'published' } },
    image: { type: Types.CloudinaryImage },
    pronunciations: { type: Types.CloudinaryImage },
    answers: { type: Types.CloudinaryImage },
    content: {
        extended: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 300 },
    },

});

Post.schema.virtual('content.full').get(function () {
    return this.content.extended || this.content.brief;
});

Post.defaultColumns = 'title, state|20%, author|20%, publishedDate|20%';
Post.register();
```

i already have the year on routes but i don't know how to use where correctly
so far .where('publishedDate').equals('2001')it shows nothing
heres a post in mongodb database from 1-1-2001

```
{"_id": ObjectID("5857b9387cf9b55946a5cae3"),
"slug": "test-exam-2001",
"title": "Test Exam 2001",
"state": "published",
"categories": [
    ObjectID("5857b80a7cf9b55946a5cadf")
],
"__v": 2,
"content": {
    "extended": "<p>empty</p>"
},
"publishedDate": ISODate("2000-12-31T22:00:00.000Z")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i got it working thanks to Shea Belsky and Jake Stockwin help

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var async = require('async');

exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {
    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
    var locals = res.locals;
    // This gets category spesified on link and then use it to show post from that category
    var val = req.url;
    var gc = val.substr(val.indexOf("&") + 1);
    // This gets Year spesified on link and then use it to show post from that year
    var gy = req.url;
    gy = gy.replace(/\D/g, '');
    gy = gy.substring(0, 4);
    // Init locals
    locals.section = 'exam_per_year';
    locals.filters = {
        category: req.params.category
    };
    locals.data = {
        posts: [],
        categories: []
    };
    // Load the posts
    view.on('init', function(next) {
        keystone.list('PostCategory').model.findOne().where('key').equals(gc).exec(function(err, results) {
            if (!err) {
                var gcid = results._id;
                var q = keystone.list('Post').paginate({
                        page: req.query.page || 1,
                        perPage: 40,
                        maxPages: 1,
                    })
                    .where('state', 'published').where('categories').equals(gcid);
                q.exec(function(err, results) {
                    var a = results.results.map(function(curResult) { //This will return only the spesified year
                        if (curResult.publishedDate.getFullYear() == gy) {
                            return curResult;
                        }
                    });
                    a = a.filter(function(element) { //This will remove every other post from the results
                        return element !== undefined;
                    });
                    locals.data.posts = a;
                    console.log(locals.data.posts);
                    next(err);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    // Render the view
    view.render('exam_per_year');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`publishedDate` is of type `Types.Date`, and anything stored in that field is stored as a JavaScript `Date` object. Therefore, you need to go a little deeper in order to pull out all the posts from a certain year.

```
view.on('init', function (next) {
   var q = keystone.list('Post').paginate({
      page: req.query.page || 1,
      perPage: 200,
      maxPages: 100,
   }).where('state', 'published');
   q.exec(function (err, results) {
      if (results.length !== 0 && !err) {
         locals.yearPosts = results.map(function (curResult) {
            return curResult.getFullYear() === 2016; // Your year goes here
         });
         return next();
      }
      else {
         // You either have no posts or there was an error loading them
      }
   });
});
```

EDIT: Changed the condition to determine if you had any results.

Comment: TypeError: results.map is not a function

Comment: So that's now just a JavaScript problem rather than anything to do with keystone. What's the output of `console.log(results)` before the `results.map`? 

IIRC, you can only call `.map` on arrays (square brackets) and not json objects (curly brackets). Regardless, the important part of this answer is the fact that you need to call `.getFullYear` as you're receiving a data object.

Comment: i cant post the results here from console.log(results) because it too long but i get 2 posts with all the info so its working before the results map i tried with square brackets still doesn't work

Comment: The result of the Keystone query should be an array, which is why `Array.map` should work. Can you do `console.log(typeof results)`? Or can you at least copy and paste part of the result (preferably the beginning or end) of what `console.log(results)` outputs?

Comment: typeoff results came up as **object** here are the console.log (results)
     { _id: 585b98423dd378460626badb,
       slug: 'another-test-2001',
       title: 'another test 2001',
       __v: 1,
       publishedDate: 2000-12-31T22:00:00.000Z,
       content: { extended: '' },
       answers: {},
       pronunciations: {},
       mainPDF: {},
       state: 'published',
       categories: [ 5857b80a7cf9b55946a5cadf ] } ],
  currentPage: 1,
  totalPages: 1,
  pages: [ 1 ],
  previous: false,
  next: false,
  first: 1,
  last: 2

Comment: I dont know if that helps but when i remove .map it says `TypeError: results is not a function` and if i use  `consol.log(results.Array.map)` it doesnt show anything...

Comment: i have added all the code on routes now maybe that will help.

Comment: So, the issue is that you're calling `findOne` not `find` on the model, and so only one result is being returned. 

If you call `find` not `findOne` then results will be an array and you can then do `results.map` (not `results.Array.map`).

Comment: That doesnt change anything i get the same error. Thats only for the category and i only need 1 selected maybe i need to use find on posts?(q variable) i will update if i get it to work if not plz help!

Comment: i added `.model.find()` on `q` (the post variable) and now i get past the error with the `.map` but now i get a new type error on `curResult.getFullYear` .... here is the error `TypeError: curResult.getFullYear is not a function`

Comment: You're doing a lot of different things and causing some clutter to accumulate. `q` is the Keystone query, you just need to call `.exec()` on it. Try this: `keystone.list('Post').model.find().exec(function (err, posts) { if (!err) { console.log(typeof posts, posts[0], posts[0].publishedDate); } });` Please post the resulting console output.

Comment: the resuls are 250 letters longer that i can post here but here is how it starts `object { _id: 585258649d9c658f02f88d83,
  slug: 'programma-diagwnismatwn-a-lykeioy-2016-2017',
  title: 'ΠΡΟΓΡΑΜΜΑ ΔΙΑΓΩΝΙΣΜΑΤΩΝ Α ΛΥΚΕΙΟΥ 2016-2017',
  __v: 1,
  publishedDate: 2016-12-14T22:00:00.000Z,
  content: 
` i used it before `q.exec(function(err, results) {`

Comment: i removed the `.model.find()` from `q`(now its `q.exec(function(err, results) {`) and now it crashes with `TypeError: results.map is not a function` again do i need to import something? i am so confused with keystone i think i will never use it again...

Comment: i have manage to get pass both of the errors by changing these `if (results.length !== 0 && !err) {locals.data.posts = results.results.map(`  and for the year `curResult.publishedDate.getFullYear()` on the log i can see the year but on the page nothing is shown

Comment: Nothing gets shown on the page unless you create something in your frontend. Do you have a `view.render` function call at the bottom of the page that points to a page template (Jade, Handlebars, EJS, etc.)? Do you still need to use `paginate` in your query, or do you only need to just get results that match the current year? In other words, is `paginate` necessary for your query or not?

Comment: i have that already before i changed the posts (to select year) it was showing all the posts from any year now it doesnt show anything i am using hbs and i am already using paginate as u see in the question ( i had it updated 3-4 days ago i think)

Comment: on the view i use this (its on handlebars)
`{{# each data.posts.results}}
<div class="post">
<h6>{{{date publishedDate format='DD-MM-YYYY'}}}<h6>
<h5><a href="{{exam_per_year_postUrl slug}}">{{{title}}}</a></h5>
<p>{{{content.brief}}}</p>
</div>
{{/each}}`

Comment: nevermind i got it working now i had to remove every undefined value now it shows the posts and everything is working right

Comment: i have posted the working routes code and hit answered there if its not ok with you you can copy paste it on your answer and i will hit answered there! thanks again for your help guys